# Install GDAL in virtualenvwrapper environment

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, gdal, virtualenvwrapper

I tried to install gdal (pip install gdal)in virtualenvwrapper environment but I got this error :

```
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for gdal
 Failed to build gdal
```

I tried also "pip install --no-install GDAL" but there is nooption --no-install

what should I do !?

Comment: Which OS is this on? pyGDAL is a little bit difficult with virtualenvs since it requires the appropriate C++ library already installed on the system. You also should match versions (i.e. if your OS has libgdal 1.9, `pip install gdal==1.9` is your friend). For Debian-based systems you also need `libgdal-dev` installed. And then there's sometimes also `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 
and also my gdal version on Os is 2.0.0 and I tried to install gdal==2.0.0 but does not work !

Comment: You need `gdal-dev` and `gdal-bin` packages. Running `pip` with `CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/gdal" pip install gdal` might also be necessary.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me !

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, installing GDAL in a venv is a doozy. Conveniently, I just wrote up the documentation on how to do so for my advisor's lab! While I am not savvy enough to pinpoint the exact cause of your error, I can give you a bunch of things to try to fix it.

First, ensure you have gdal installed on the host (i.e. not in a venv). I just run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal1i libgdal1-dev libgdal-dev
```

Now run `gdal-config --version` to get the version that `apt-get` provided you with. For example I get `1.11.3`

Now, the easiest way in my experience to get the python bindings in a venv is using `pygdal`. The trick is to get the right version! To do so, activate your virtual environment and run

```
pip install pygdal==1.11.3
```

but replace the version with whatever you got from `gdal-config --version`. Note: you may get an error that says

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygdal==1.11.3 (from versions: 1.8.1.0, 1.8.1.1, 1.8.1.2, 1.8.1.3, 1.9.2.0, 1.9.2.1, 1.9.2.3, 1.10.0.0, 1.10.0.1, 1.10.0.3, 1.10.1.0, 1.10.1.1, 1.10.1.3, 1.11.0.0, 1.11.0.1, 1.11.0.3, 1.11.1.0, 1.11.1.1, 1.11.1.3, 1.11.2.1, 1.11.2.3, 1.11.3.3, 1.11.4.3, 2.1.0.3) No matching distribution found for pygdal==1.11.3
```

If that happens, run the `pip install` again but with the highest version that still matches. e.g. in this case you would run `pip install pygdal==1.11.3.3`

Once `pygdal` has been successfully installed, you should be able to call

```
>>> from osgeo import gdal
```

Please let me know if anything fails and I'll do what I can to adjust my instructions. Also, if you need help with Proj.4, GEOS, or Cartopy, I have some experience there too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Especially for the "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygdal==1.11.3 (from versions: ....)" error.

Comment: These instructions really helped me to get Kartograph.py working, thank you

Comment: Cheers mate. I think the mentioning the version worked for me!

Comment: Thanks, medley56 this was helpful

Comment: Versions now contain four numbers: `pip install pygdal==1.11.3.3`

Comment: This worked for me on my ubuntu 18.04. Later, I'll need the same on my 20.04 servers. Will let you all know if this worked flawlessly there as well.

Answer (score 6):

use [pygdal](https://github.com/dezhin/pygdal/)

```
pd@asghar:~$sudo apt-get install python3-gdal 

pd@asghar:~$ virtualenv -p python3 test
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/pd/test/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/pd/test/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

pd@asghar:~$  gdal-config --version
2.1.3
pd@asghar:~$ test/bin/pip install pygdal==2.1.3
Collecting pygdal==2.1.3
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygdal==2.1.3 (from versions: 1.8.1.0, 1.8.1.1, 1.8.1.2, 1.8.1.3, 1.9.2.0, 1.9.2.1, 1.9.2.3, 1.10.0.0, 1.10.0.1, 1.10.0.3, 1.10.1.0, 1.10.1.1, 1.10.1.3, 1.11.0.0, 1.11.0.1, 1.11.0.3, 1.11.1.0, 1.11.1.1, 1.11.1.3, 1.11.2.1, 1.11.2.3, 1.11.3.3, 1.11.4.3, 1.11.5.3, 2.0.0.3, 2.0.1.3, 2.0.2.3, 2.0.3.3, 2.1.0.3, 2.1.1.3, 2.1.2.3, 2.1.3.3, 2.2.0.3)
No matching distribution found for pygdal==2.1.3
pd@asghar:~$ test/bin/pip install pygdal==2.1.3.3
Collecting pygdal==2.1.3.3
Collecting numpy>=1.0.0 (from pygdal==2.1.3.3)
  Using cached numpy-1.13.1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy, pygdal
Successfully installed numpy-1.13.1 pygdal-2.1.3.3
pd@asghar:~$ source test/bin/activate
(test) pd@asghar:~$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from osgeo import gdal
>>>
```

Comment: It worked for me on OSX HighSIerra and Python3.6: `pip install pygdal` and then `from osgeo import gdal`.

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS, first do brew install:

```
brew install gdal
```

Then do pip install:

```
pip install gdal
```

Comment: No, this is not working with virtualenv. To do so, you have to link. So: 
`brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac` then `brew install osgeo-gdal && brew install osgeo-gdal-python` finally `brew link osgeo-gdal --force && brew link osgeo-gdal-python --force`. Then you can `pip install gdal` in any virtualenv.